# Understanding the behavior of processes - why all process run together and sleep together?

Tags: shell, multiprocessing

I have written a script to initiate multi-processing

```
for i in `seq 1 $1`
do
        /usr/bin/php index.php name&
done

wait
```

A cron run every min - `myscript.sh 3`  now three background process get initiated and after some time I see list of process via ps command. I see all the processes are together in "Sleep" or  "Running" mode...Now I wanted to achieve that when one goes to sleep other processes must process..how can I achieve it?. Or this is normal.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal. A program that can run *will* be given time by the operating system... when possible. If all three are sleeping, then the system is most likely busy and time is being given to other processes.